# Synchronize threaded write into file using synchronizers

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I'm writing to a file via multiple threads so I am using the following code:

```
            synchronized (this) {
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter(path, true));
                bw.write(data);
            }
```

and I'm wondering for educational purposes how I can use some synchronizer (Semaphore, CountDownLatch, CyclicBarrier, Phaser or Exchanger) to essentially achieve the same thing: safe multithreaded writing.

Thanks

Comment: Well, you need to learn what each of them is, decide which one to use, and use them ;-) As is, your question is too broad I fear - there are too many possible answers - actually, books could be written about this topic. A starting point: [java.util.concurrent JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, the much better nearly tautological way to write from multiple sources to the same writer is to use a (blocking) queue. This way, all threads can drop their messages on the queue, and the writer thread can pick the messages off the queue and write them to the file. It's generally easier to implement, as well as more efficient

-- edit --

Example:

```
public class MyQueueableWriter implements Runnable {
  private BlockingQueue<Msg> q = new BlockingQueue();
  private FileOutputStream fis = ...;
  private volatile boolean running = true;

  public MyQueueableWriter(FileOutputStream fis) {
    this.fis = fis;
  }
  
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (running) {
        Message m = q.take();
        fis.write(...);
      }
      fis.close();
    } catch (IOException iox) {
      ...
    }
  }

  public void addMsg(Msg m) {
    q.put(m);
  }

  public void stop() {
    running = false;
  }
}
```

Then adding to the queue:

```
public class EnqueueMsgRunnable implements Runnable {
  MyQueueableWriter q = ...;
  q.put(myMessage);
  q.put(myMessage2);
}
```

Then just

```
for (int i =0; i < numSources; i++) {
  EnqueueMsgRunnable r = new EnqueueMsgRunnable(...);
  new Thread(r).start();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that sounds interesting. Could you please show me a simple example on how to implement this so I can try this on my own?

Comment: @Daniel there is a producer-consumer example in the JavaDocs for [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). In your case, the consumer would write to the file, while the producers write to the queue.